# CSS '+', call more than one pseudo-class

Tags: css

So I know all this can be done in Javascript without much difficulty, but wondered if, in the end it could all be done with CSS. I tried looking at a number of entries on here, many say 'no'-- but they are also quite old (circa 2014) so I don't know if the CSS standard has been updated significantly since then.

I've two classes .arrow and .slide. I've done the checkbox hack to be able to activate .slide on a click by #test:checked + .slide.

In part I am wondering if it is possible to chain more than one CSS Selector together, or does that not work ? I.e. something like #test:checked + .slide + .arrow2 + etc..

The specific 'second' action I wish to occur has presently been stuffed away in .arrow:active, because I wasn't sure how else to demonstrate it.
Go over to the right to the arrows, do a long hold click and you will see the state change I want to happen. I mean if you click the arrows twice, .slide goes in and out just fine.

I'm just not sure how to achieve the same state change with .arrow, or if it is possible to pull both into one event without resorting to JS.

Outta ideas...

```css
.arrow {
  width: 19px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right; 
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-image: url("http://www.allpointsbulletin.info/assets/img/ArrowDown.png"); 
  transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.arrow:active {
  background-image: url("https://www.allpointsbulletin.info/assets/img/ArrowUp.png");
}

.slide {
  clear:both;
  width:10%;
  height:0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  transition: height 1.5s ease;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slide li {
  padding : 30px;
}

#test {
  position: absolute; 
  opacity: 0; 
  height: 0px;}    

#test:checked + .slide {height: 500px;}
```

```html
<label for="test"><h4>See more info<div class="arrow"></div></h4></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="test">
<ul class="slide">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question. Please do not just point us to code linked to another website. Code on that site might change or disappear over time, leaving the question here without any context for future readers. Your question becomes much easier to answer when the code you want help with is actually in the question.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I didn't know you could do that. And if in the end the answer is 'just use JS' that is fine. I am not looking for a 'solution'. I just didn't know if the standards in CSS had been updated to the point where such a thing is possible.

Comment: So you want the arrows to change to point upward when the checkbox is active?

Comment: That is what I was going for-- But it was also a matter of whether if it was possible to link multiple  CSS state changes together based on a single event. Already have some great replies/answers so far. See below.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<label>` cannot contain a  `<h4>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the checkbox before everything because the flow of an [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) is left to right on the CSS selector syntax and HTML element directly ahead of the previous HTML element.

**Details are commented in example**

```css
:root {
  font: 3ch/1.15 "Segoe UI";
}

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#switch {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 90vw;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  border-bottom: 2px ridge grey;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow {
  display: block;
  width: 1.25rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background: url(https://www.allpointsbulletin.info/assets/img/ArrowUp.png) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Default is 0deg */
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  /* Assign a transition for all animatable properties */
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/* When the checkbox is (:checked), go to the (+) .button
directly ahead of it then go to the .arrow inside of 
.button. Rotate .arrow 180deg. */
#switch:checked +.button .arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.slide {
  list-style: none;
  width: 10rem;
  /* Default height is 0 */
  height: 0;
  /* Hides content when height: 0 */
  overflow: hidden;  
  /* Assign a transition for all animatable properties */
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.slide a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}

/* When checkbox is (:checked), go to (+) .button directly ahead of
it, then go to (+) .slide directly ahead of .button. Change .slide
height to 500px. */
#switch:checked +.button +.slide {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<input id="switch" type="checkbox">
<label for="switch" class="button">Sections<b class="arrow"></b></label>
<ul class="slide">
  <li><a href="#">Section I</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Section II</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Section III</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Section IV</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh, this is really cool too. Plus, more to the benefit of others, I know I asked my question in a rather awkward way (whether pseudo-class chaining (i.e. here the #switch:checked +.button +.slide, as you have shown) was possible or not, and you demonstrate that it is. I tried searching for other examples of chaining but couldn't find any. With this in mind I can think of a lot of other cool barebones CSS applications could be performed. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using CSS. You need to use `:has()` pseudo selector for that and also use a parent container. The changes:

```
.parent:has(#test:checked) .arrow{
  background-image: url("https://www.allpointsbulletin.info/assets/img/ArrowUp.png");
}
```

And you don't need `.arrow:active` pseudo selector anymore.
Note: This `:has()` pseudo selector has limited browser support.

```css
.arrow {
  width: 19px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right; 
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-image: url("http://www.allpointsbulletin.info/assets/img/ArrowDown.png"); 
  transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* .arrow:active {
  background-image: url("https://www.allpointsbulletin.info/assets/img/ArrowUp.png");
} */

.slide {
  clear:both;
  width:10%;
  height:0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  transition: height 1.5s ease;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slide li {
  padding : 30px;
}

#test {
  position: absolute; 
  opacity: 0; 
  height: 0px;}    

#test:checked + .slide {height: 500px;} 

.parent:has(#test:checked) .arrow{
  background-image: url("https://www.allpointsbulletin.info/assets/img/ArrowUp.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <label for="test"><h4>See more info<div class="arrow"></div></h4></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="test">
  <ul class="slide">
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As mentioned `:has()` is not supported everywhere. Of note it is not currently supported in Firefox: https://caniuse.com/css-has

Comment: Oh, cool, thank you. I had a feeling the CSS standards had advanced. I was looking through the loong Mozilla list of CSS Pseudo-classes and wasn't sure which one might work. I tried :indeterminate, but obviously that was not working.

Comment: Thanks Chris. And you are welcome Nevermnd. I just checked `:indeterminate` requires JavaScript which you were not trying to use here. Right?

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam I mean I *can* use JavaScript, I just have a tendency to avoid using it if I don't *have* to just to play around a little with the DOM. Personally, I find CSS more elegant in structure too. To me, at this point I think JS is useful if you want to run advanced calculations, produce advanced animations, etc locally.  But once I started to play around with this, rather than just give up and go with JS, I didn't know if it was possible. Thank you though for your insight. I am only slowly working on a personal website... Not microsoft.com.